# SVG image with a border / stroke

Tags: svg

I'm trying to add a border around an SVG image. I have tried 2 approaches, but both failed...

Attempt 1: Draws image but no border

```
<image id="note-0" xlink:href="http://example.com/example.png" x="185" y="79" height="202" width="150" style="stroke:#ac0d0d; stroke-width:3;"></image>
```

Attempt 2: Draws image but no border

```
<defs>
    <image id="image1352022098990svg" height="202" width="150" xlink:href="http://example.com/example.png"></image>
</defs>
                
<use xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="note-0" xlink:href="#image1352022098990svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="185" y="79" height="202" width="150" style="stroke:#ac0d0d; stroke-width:3;"/>
```

So my question is, is it possible to define an image on an SVG element and have a border/stroke around it at the same time?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[stroke](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeProperties) does not apply to `<image>` or `<use>`, only shapes and text. If you want to draw a border round it, draw a `<rect>` after the image with the same x,y,width and height as the image and give that a stroke and a fill of "none".

As to translate vs x/y - it depends on your use case.

Comment: Could this border exactly follows image's shape?

Comment: @new2cpp You could trace a path in a tool such as Inkscape round any shape you want.

Answer (score 13):

If for some reason you cannot change the SVG elements, there is a workaround using the outline CSS property:

```
#note-0 {
    outline: 6px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need it to wrap around a circular image (svg shape for example), and you just need some color to outline it, you may find something like this useful:

```
image { 
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px red);
}
```