# Rectangle border around SVG text

Tags: css, svg

Trying to put a border around some SVG text, and I am getting varying results.

HTML: (with the mute class)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <text x="37.5" y="37.5" class="ablate-x mute">X</text>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.ablate-x {
   font-size: 24px;
   color: gray;
   opacity: 0.5;
   font-weight: 900;
   cursor: hand;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.mute {
   opacity: 1;
   fill: red;
   stroke: red;
   stroke-width: 2px;
   /* we tried border: 2px solid red;   but it didn't work */
}
```

D3.js:

```
.on("click", function(d) {
    var selection = d3.select(this);
    selection.classed("mute", (selection.classed("mute") ? false : true));
 })
```

Here we have the `X` without the mute class [image: grey]

Here we have the `X` with the mute class [image: red] but without the border

This is what we are trying to get the border to look like [image: red with border]

Note: its parent is a group, not an HTML element.

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/yuRyr/5/

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217669/svg-image-with-a-border-stroke) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001950/how-can-i-draw-a-box-around-text-with-svg) should help.

Answer (score 21):

SVG elements don't support the CSS border property as you have discovered. Your options are

1. Draw a red `<rect>` around the text as a border
2. Put a border on the outer `<svg>` element if its parent is a html element. The outer `<svg>` element is a replaced element and will support the CSS border property.

Comment: What all css properties are not supported by svg ?

Answer (score 13):

To draw a rect around text on click, update the code to:

```
var svgcanvas = d3.select('svg');

$("#xc").on("click", function (d) {
    var selection = d3.select(this);
    var rect = this.getBBox();
    var offset = 2; // enlarge rect box 2 px on left & right side
    selection.classed("mute", (selection.classed("mute") ? false : true));

    pathinfo = [
        {x: rect.x-offset, y: rect.y }, 
        {x: rect.x+offset + rect.width, y: rect.y}, 
        {x: rect.x+offset + rect.width, y: rect.y + rect.height }, 
        {x: rect.x-offset, y: rect.y + rect.height},
        {x: rect.x-offset, y: rect.y },
    ];

    // Specify the function for generating path data
    var d3line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d){return d.x;})
        .y(function(d){return d.y;})
        .interpolate("linear"); 
    // Draw the line
    svgcanvas.append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", d3line(pathinfo))
        .style("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("stroke", "red")
        .style("fill", "none");

})
```

On this html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="720" height="720">
            <text x="37.5" y="37.5" id="xc">X</text>
        </svg>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I was trying to position a `rect` first. I find this solution much more elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With newer versions of d3.js, there's no `interpolate()` function on the line generator (reference: ["Interpolate" is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198378)), so I somewhat modified Alvin K's answer as shown in the code below (Typescript). In particular, the code is used to simulate a hover effect on an SVG text.

```ts
    const group = d3.select(/* your node */)
    group
        .append("rect")
        .attr("stroke", "none")
        .attr("fill", "none")

    group
        .append("text")
        .call((node) => {
            node.on("mouseenter", function(this: any) {
                const rect = this.getBBox()
                d3.select(this.parentNode)
                    .select("rect")
                    .attr("x", rect.x - offset)
                    .attr("y", rect.y - offset)
                    .attr("width", rect.width + offset * 2)
                    .attr("height", rect.height + offset * 2)
                    .style("stroke-width", 1)
                    .style("stroke", "black")
                    .style("stroke-dasharray", "4")
                    .style("fill", "none");
                })
            node.on("mouseleave", function(this: any) {
                d3.select(this.parentNode)
                    .select("rect")
                    .style("stroke", "none")
            })
        })
```

PS: it's not necessary to use `call()` on the selection, you could just call `on()` directly, however in my actual code, I refactored the callback into a class method.

```js
var offset = 5
onload();

function onload() {
    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 200)
                .attr("height", 200)

    const group = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(10, 40)")
    group
        .append("rect")
        .attr("stroke", "none")
        .attr("fill", "none")

    group
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("font-weight", 600)
        .attr("font-size", "16px")
        .text("HOVER ON ME")
        .call((node) => {
            node.on("mouseenter", function() {
                const rect = this.getBBox()
                d3.select(this.parentNode)
                    .select("rect")
                    .attr("x", rect.x - offset)
                    .attr("y", rect.y - offset)
                    .attr("width", rect.width + offset * 2)
                    .attr("height", rect.height + offset * 2)
                    .style("stroke-width", 1)
                    .style("stroke", "black")
                    .style("stroke-dasharray", "4")
                    .style("fill", "none");
                })
            node.on("mouseleave", function() {
                d3.select(this.parentNode)
                    .select("rect")
                    .style("stroke", "none")
            })
        })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
```