# React Native - SVG Image is not scaling across different device dimensions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg, responsive-design

I am trying to develop a simple screen in react native where it displays an svg image. I am trying to make the svg image use the full device width and height (100%). But the problem is, it is not consistent across different devices. For example, it is rendering properly in Iphone 8 Plus but not scaling properly in Ipad or Iphone 8. I heard the SVG files are scalable across all devices without losing quality. But I am not sure what I am missing here. I have posted the code and images below for reference.

Before posting here, I have did a considerable amount of research in Github and here as well.
I have also followed the steps mentioned in one of the similar posts ([How to find correct values for width, height and viewBox with react-native-svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657859/how-to-find-correct-values-for-width-height-and-viewbox-with-react-native-svg)) but its not working. Can any please guide me on the right direction to fix the issue.

**React Native Screen Component Code**

```
import * as React from "react";
import Svg, { Defs, G, Path, Text, TSpan, Circle } from "react-native-svg";
/* SVGR has dropped some elements not supported by react-native-svg: style */

import { Dimensions, View } from "react-native";

function SvgComponent(props) {
  const originalWidth = 1080;
  const originalHeight = 1920;

  const aspectRatio = originalWidth / originalHeight;
  const windowWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;

  return (
    <View style={{ width: windowWidth, aspectRatio }}>
      <Svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        viewBox="0 0 1080 1920"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      >
        <Defs></Defs>
        <G id="prefix__Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
          <G id="prefix__Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
            <Path fill="#006837" d="M.5.5h1079v1919H.5z" />
            <Path d="M1079 1v1918H1V1h1078m1-1H0v1920h1080V0z" />
            <Text
              transform="matrix(1.5 0 0 1 13 148.09)"
              fontFamily="ArialMT,Arial"
              fill="#fff"
              fontSize={106}
            >
              <TSpan className="prefix__cls-3">{"T"}</TSpan>
              <TSpan x={62.83} y={0}>
                {"O"}
              </TSpan>
              <TSpan x={145.28} y={0} letterSpacing="-.02em">
                {"P"}
              </TSpan>
              <TSpan x={214.07} y={0} />
              <TSpan x={243.52} y={0} letterSpacing="-.07em">
                {"P"}
              </TSpan>
              <TSpan x={306.35} y={0} letterSpacing={0}>
                {"AGE"}
              </TSpan>
              <TSpan className="prefix__cls-3" x={530.21} y={0} />
              <TSpan x={557.74} y={0}>
                {"TS"}
              </TSpan>
            </Text>
            <Text
              transform="matrix(1.5 0 0 1 13 1888.09)"
              fontSize={79}
              fontFamily="ArialMT,Arial"
              fill="#fff"
            >
              {"BOT"}
              <TSpan className="prefix__cls-8" x={162.4} y={0}>
                {"T"}
              </TSpan>
              <TSpan x={209.23} y={0}>
                {"OM "}
              </TSpan>
              <TSpan x={358.43} y={0} letterSpacing="-.07em">
                {"P"}
              </TSpan>
              <TSpan x={405.26} y={0}>
                {"AGE"}
              </TSpan>
              <TSpan className="prefix__cls-8" x={572.09} y={0} />
              <TSpan x={592.62} y={0}>
                {"TS"}
              </TSpan>
            </Text>
            <Circle className="prefix__cls-10" cx={514.5} cy={396.5} r={129} />
            <Path d="M514.5 268a128.51 128.51 0 11-90.86 37.64A127.66 127.66 0 01514.5 268m0-1A129.5 129.5 0 10644 396.5 129.5 129.5 0 00514.5 267z" />
            <Circle className="prefix__cls-10" cx={179.5} cy={729.5} r={129} />
            <Path d="M179.5 601a128.51 128.51 0 11-90.86 37.64A127.66 127.66 0 01179.5 601m0-1A129.5 129.5 0 10309 729.5 129.5 129.5 0 00179.5 600z" />
            <Circle className="prefix__cls-10" cx={852.5} cy={748.5} r={129} />
            <Path d="M852.5 620a128.51 128.51 0 11-90.86 37.64A127.66 127.66 0 01852.5 620m0-1A129.5 129.5 0 10982 748.5 129.5 129.5 0 00852.5 619z" />
            <Circle className="prefix__cls-10" cx={514.5} cy={1007.5} r={129} />
            <Path d="M514.5 879a128.51 128.51 0 11-90.86 37.64A127.66 127.66 0 01514.5 879m0-1A129.5 129.5 0 10644 1007.5 129.5 129.5 0 00514.5 878z" />
            <Path
              className="prefix__cls-10"
              d="M36.99 1244.17l-28.95-91.2 64.51-70.67 93.46 20.53 28.95 91.2-64.51 70.67-93.46-20.53z"
            />
            <Path d="M72.72 1082.85l92.9 20.4 28.77 90.65-64.11 70.25-92.9-20.4-28.77-90.65 64.11-70.25m-.34-1.1l-64.9 71.1 29.12 91.75 94 20.65 64.9-71.1-29.1-91.75-94-20.65z" />
            <Path
              className="prefix__cls-10"
              d="M863.74 1280.56l-66.18-120.49 71.26-117.56 137.44 2.93 66.18 120.49-71.26 117.56-137.44-2.93z"
            />
            <Path d="M869.1 1043l136.86 2.92 65.9 120-71 117.07-136.86-2.92-65.9-120 71-117.07m-.56-1l-71.56 118 66.46 121 138 3 71.56-118-66.46-121-138-3z" />
            <Path
              className="prefix__cls-10"
              d="M293.27 1553.17l35.61-150.02 147.73-44.18 112.12 105.86-35.61 150.02-147.73 44.18-112.12-105.86z"
            />
            <Path d="M476.48 1359.53L588.18 1465l-35.48 149.46-147.18 44L293.82 1553l35.48-149.47 147.18-44m.26-1.12l-148.28 44.34-35.75 150.59 112.55 106.25 148.28-44.34 35.75-150.59-112.55-106.25z" />
            <Path
              className="prefix__cls-10"
              d="M708.09 1692.49a21.08 21.08 0 01-20.4-26l54.77-230.76a21 21 0 0120.54-16.16 20.61 20.61 0 0114 5.37l185.77 166a21.07 21.07 0 01-8.55 36l-240.55 64.78a21.15 21.15 0 01-5.58.77z"
            />
            <Path d="M763 1419.07v1a20.16 20.16 0 0113.61 5.24l185.77 166a20.55 20.55 0 01-8.35 35.18l-240.55 64.79a21 21 0 01-5.43.73 20.58 20.58 0 01-19.92-25.33L743 1435.9a20.54 20.54 0 0120-15.83v-1m0 0a21.53 21.53 0 00-21 16.59l-54.8 230.76a21.49 21.49 0 0026.58 25.8l240.55-64.78a21.56 21.56 0 008.76-36.9l-185.77-166a21.27 21.27 0 00-14.29-5.5z" />
          </G>
        </G>
      </Svg>
    </View>
  );
}

export default SvgComponent;
```

**Perfect Rendering in Iphone 8 Plus**

[image: Iphone-8 Plues]

**Bad Rendering in IPad**

[image: Ipad]

Comment: can anyone please help if you are aware of the issue

Comment: SVG can scale of course but elements are not going to "move magically" within the image to fit a new aspect ratio.
Please explain what you want to display by creating a mockup of what it should look like. To me, your image for the iPad is okay. The SVG on the ipad is simply scaled to fit the width of the device. The height is of course higher than the device since the ipad is more "square" (aspect ratio is different) and your "bottom text" is clipped away. Do you want to scale the image to fit the height instead?  If you do, there will be areas on the side where there is no image of course.

Comment: One option is to "stretch or squash" the image to fit 100% width and 100% height - which will probably look absolutely horrible (circles are going to look like ellipses).
Another option is to split in multiple SVGs that would be aligned to the edge and centered and have layout logic in React Native to correctly position the different SVGs pieces. They can overlap if there is no background color.