# How to put a border and hyperlink on a image tag inside a svg tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a svg tag with several image tags in it, something like this

```
<svg>
    <image fill-opacity="0.6" style="fill-opacity: 0.6; cursor: move;" xlink:href="http://mysite/arin/site/../pics/category/7/7.png" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="133" width="359.79999999999995" y="779.5" x="2033.5"></image>
</svg>
```

This gets generated by the plugin 
http://www.graphdracula.net/ which makes svg graphs. It lets me drag the nodes around which is good.

But how can I dynamically add a `black 1px solid` `border` around the image, and also add a `onclick` event to it, so if I click it, something will happen, and also still keep the drag functionality.

```
function showGraph(obj) {
    var width = $(document).width() * 3;
    var height = $(document).height() * 3;
    var g = new Graph();

    var categories = obj['category_data'];  
    for(var i=0; i<categories.length; i+=1) {
        var cat_data = categories[i];

        var id = cat_data['id'];
        var name = cat_data['name'];
        var images = cat_data['images'];

        var render = null;
        for(var j=0; j<images.length; j+=1) {
            var image = images[j];
            if (image['approved']==1 && image['main']==1) {
                var info = image['info'];
                var link = info['elink'];
                var ow = info['width'];
                var oh = info['height'];

                var w = 150;
                var h = (w*oh) / ow;
                var w = ow*0.7;
                var h = oh*0.7;

                render = getRenderer(link, w, h);
                break;
            }
        }

        g.addNode(id, { label : name, render : render });
    }
    for(var i=0; i<categories.length; i+=1) {
        var cat_data = categories[i];
        var id = cat_data['id'];
        var pid = cat_data['parent_id'];
        if (pid != 0) {
            g.addEdge(pid, id, { directed : true });
        }
    }

    var layouter = new Graph.Layout.Spring(g);

    var renderer = new Graph.Renderer.Raphael('canvas', g, width, height);

    var images = $("image");
    images.css("border", "1px solid black");
    images.dblclick(function() {
        alert(1);
    });
}

function getRenderer(link, w, h) {
    return function(r, n) {
        var set = r.set().push(r.image(link, 10, 10, w, h));
        return set;
    };
}
```

Comment: Post the code you are using to generate the SVG output.

Comment: I added the code, the jquery onclick worked, but it still fired when I dragged, so I guess I can go with double click... But the border thing isn't working...

Comment: That's because it's SVG markup, not HTML.  CSS attributes don't necessarily affect SVG elements.

Comment: So how can I add the border?

Comment: It looks like the SVG elements are being created by RaphaelJS.  You need to first obtain the Raphael Element Object of the image, then apply attribute to it using the `element.attr()` function: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr

Comment: I was testing in developer tools, and I manually added `stroke="blue"` to it like this site says https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes, but it didnt change anything.

Comment: Try also adding `stroke-width="5"`

Comment: Recreate your code in a JSfiddle.  Can't really help you much more without seeing it action.

Answer (score 0):

As per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13217794/1332068

> [stroke](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeProperties) does not apply to <image> or <use>, only shapes and text.

You cannot add a stroke to an SVG image.  You must create a rectangle with the same path and position of the image, then outline the rectangle with a stroke.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that you cannot apply a stroke to an SVG image.  See my updated answer for an alternative suggestion.

Comment: if I do that, then If I drag it, will it move the image and the rectangle?