# Trying to create an SVG with a grid of images. But the images don't show

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to create a grid layout of Images on top of an SVG.
But when I append an image tag on my SVG it does not show. I did change the tag from img to image and append svg/image
But it does not seem to work. I am able to achieve it with plan D3.js but I need SVG as I want to invoke the D3brush functionality. Below is my code.

**Code with SVG**

```js
var svg = d3.select("#gridchart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .classed("grid-container",true);

var grid = svg.append("div")
            .attr("id", "grid")
            .attr("class", "grid");

patch = grid
    .selectAll("image")
    .data(selectedData)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("id",function(d, i) { return "patchid_"+d[0]})
    .attr("class",function(d, i) { return "patch"+d[4]+" select_patch"})
    .attr("xlink:href", "train_10_0_0.png")
    .attr("width", "32px")
    .attr("height", "32px");
```

Code with D3

```js
grid = d3.select("#gridchart")
   .append("div")
   .attr("id", "grid")
   .attr("class", "grid")
;

patch = grid
    .selectAll("img")
    .data(selectedData)
    .enter()
    .append("img")
    .attr("id",function(d, i) { return "patchid_"+d[0]})
    .attr("class",function(d, i) { return "patch"+d[4]+" select_patch"})
    .attr("src","train_10_0_0.png")
    .attr("width", "32px")
    .attr("height", "32px");
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a `div` to an `svg`, you broke it's rendering. I replaced that with a `g`-tag and things started working directly. Here's some example.

```js
var svg = d3.select("#gridchart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 200)
  .classed("grid-container", true);

var grid = svg.append("g")
  .attr("id", "grid")
  .attr("class", "grid");

var selectedData = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

grid
  .selectAll("image")
  .data(selectedData)
  .enter()
  .append("svg:image")
  .attr("id", function(d, i) {
    return "patchid_" + d
  })
  .attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return "patch" + d + " select_patch"
  })
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://via.placeholder.com/32")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + ((i % 3) * 50) + ", " + (Math.floor(i / 3) * 50) + ")";
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="gridchart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, yes I did that as I was not able to apply styles to the image objects that I was appending, wanted each image to have a colored border.

Comment: Ah yes, you can do that by drawing a `rect` behind each image, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13217669/5015356)